# Simple vector- display one message if in out of range, different message if in range

Tags: r

I'm trying to get R to print a statement if in range or a different one if not.

My code:

```
temps <- c(34, 90, 93, 52, 108)
if (temps < 40) {
  print("Stay Home!")
} else if (temps > 100) {
  print("Stay Home!")
} else
  print("Go Run!")
```

###or, second try...

```
temps <- c(34, 90, 93, 52, 108)
if(any(temps < 40)) print("Stay Home!")
if(any(temps > 100)) print("Stay Home!")
ifelse(print("Go Run!"))
```

I'm getting Error: unexpected 'else' in "else"

and the other is printing both.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your last else is missing { } to wrap around the print command

Comment: Ah, thanks! It's printing both statements though... should they all be "ifelse" or do I need an "or?"

Comment: Sorry, I was paying enough attention to your code. Try `ifelse(temps < 40 | temps > 100, "Stay Home!", "Go Run!")`.

Comment: Thanks so much! I forgot about that | operator.
*EDIT - What if I want to run it against the whole vector? i.e any outliers return "Stay Home!"

Just change ifelse to if?

Comment: The code as I've given it will go through the whole vector.